# How do I get the Google Plus app to ignore videos I loaded onto my phone?

Tags: google-plus, filter, instant-upload

I recently loaded some videos from my PC to my phone (running Jelly Bean) and got the most recent Google Plus app. I was going to turn on 'Instant Upload' so that it backs up my photos quickly, but realized that it also wants to upload the videos I put on my phone.

Is there a way I can get it to not upload videos from my phone (or have it ignore things in a certain directory on my phone)?

Comment: Why not try putting in a `.nomedia` in a certain directory, an empty file that is. IE, a dot filename which is marked as hidden by the Linux filesystem...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to stop the Google Plus from auto uploading video if you have instant upload turn on.

The work around I can think off is to use a file manager like "Astro" to move all your video file from /DCIM/Camera folder to a different folder in your sdcard.  I believe Google Plus will ignore the folder outside of /DCIM/

EDIT: Re-read your post, looks like you were uploading video from your PC to your phone which you probably just placing those under some folder in sdcard.

You can try this app [StudioKUMA .nomedia Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.studiokuma.nomedia) and set the folder that contains video with .nomedia and perhaps the entire folder will be ignore by Google+

Comment: I seriously doubt that he moved the videos there.

Comment: Or skip using the app and just add your own .nomedia file to the folder.

Answer (score -1):

There is: open photos app (Google's one of course), go to 'on device' menu and tap right-hand side cloud icon on any folder you want.